# Ruby library to generate graphics from text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphics, google-maps

I'm working in Rails and I'm looking for a library/gem/plugin to generate a graphic from text. Google Maps doesn't allow you to overlay text, only graphics so I'm looking for a back door to overlay text. Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/).

To draw text using RMagick, you need to use one the [text](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html#text) or [annotate](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/draw.html#annotate) methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like [RMagick](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/), though that particular library has been known to leak memory.

Answer (score 1):

[`libgd`](http://www.libgd.org/) can do this, and has bindings for many different languages, including [Ruby](http://www.libgd.org/Binders#Ruby)